# Fortran DMOD vs Python numpy.remainder

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, modulo

Why do I get different results using "DMOD" in Fortran and "numpy.remainder" in Python?

In Fortran:

```
DOUBLE PRECISION aaa,bbb
aaa = 2.11561
bbb = 1.19841
out = DMOD(aaa, bbb)
print*,out
```

and I get: 0.917199850

In python:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.remainder(2.11561,1.19841))
```

and I get: 0.9172000000000002

Comment: Your Fortran constants are single-precision.  Double precision constants have a different syntax, e.g. `1.2D9` (the `D` indicates double precision).

Comment: Not also dmod is archaic since the new-fangled overloading of intrinsic functions that came into the language in 1977. Simply use Mod( aaa, bbb )

Comment: Thanks. My example is with DMOD because I'm converting a Fortran 77 code to python. If I use D (aaa = 2.11561D0) I get 0.917200029 that is closer but not perfect

Comment: You have to add `out` to the list of variables that are declared to be `double precision`: `DOUBLE PRECISION aaa,bbb,out`

Comment: Your variable `out` is implicitly `real`, which causes the result to be converted to single-precision.  To retain the full double-precision result, you need to declare `out` to be `double`.  That may account for the remaining difference.

Comment: @scana MOD was preferable to DMOD already in Fortran 77.

Comment: Thanks Warren and Tom, that (out as double precision) solved the problem. I'm converting this old code and there are a lot of missed declarations that definitively need to be checked.

Comment: IMPLICIT NONE is your friend ... always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want double-precision in Fortran, you need to write the constants that way too. You might do it this way, by using a `_dp` suffix:

```
integer, parameter:: dp=kind(0.d0)
aaa = 2.11561_dp
```

Or you might use the `d` in the number:

```
aaa = 2.11561d0
```

You use `e` for single precision and `d` for double precision. Single precision is default... and even if the variable is double-precision, the constant might be single-precision! It is the same way in C.

The difference is that Python and C use double-precision by default, and you have to ask for single precision.

Comment: Thanks, If I use D (aaa = 2.11561D0, and so bbb) I get 0.917200029 that is closer but not perfect

Comment: @scana: Probably because `out` is single precision.

Comment: even better imo is `use iso_fortran_env, only: RK => real64; real(RK) :: aaa = 2.11561_RK`